# Duplicated footer html/css on another page, but shows up differently?

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm making a website and I completed the main page (header, body, and footer). I started a new  document for my second page. I copied and pasted the code for the header from the main page into the second page and that worked flawlessly. But when I did the same for my footer, it resulted in my footer aligning left instead of aligning center. All the code and the html are the same. I don't know what the problem is. I've been looking everywhere but had no luck so far.

CSS Code:

```
.end_text {
    width: 100%;
}

.bottom_left li {
    float:left;
    list-style: none;
}

.bottom_lmid li {
    float:left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.bottom_lmid li:first-child {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.bottom_rmid li {
    float:left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.bottom_rmid li:first-child {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.bottom_right li {
    float:left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.bottom_right li:first-child {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="foot_bar">
        <img src="../../images/bestfoodservicesweb_24.jpg" width="862"/>
    </div>
  <div class="end_text">
            <ul class="bottom_left">
                <li><img src="../../images/bestfoodservicesweb_34.jpg" width="80" height="26"/></li>
           </ul>
            <ul class="bottom_lmid">
                <li><img src="../../images/bestfoodservicesweb_37.jpg" width="63" height="16"/></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.bestfoodservice.us/contact.aspx"><img src="../../images/bestfoodservicesweb_38.jpg" width="63" height="16"/></a></li>
                <li><img src="../../images/bestfoodservicesweb_39.jpg" width="99" height="16"/></li>
               </ul>
                <ul class="bottom_rmid">
                    <li><img src="../../images/bestfoodservicesweb_41.jpg" width="26" height="14"/></li>
                    <li><img src="../../images/bestfoodservicesweb_43.jpg" width="38" height="15"/></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="bottom_right">
                        <li><a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="../../images/bestfoodservicesweb_27.jpg" width="25" height="25"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="../../images/bestfoodservicesweb_29.jpg" width="25" height="25"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://linkedin.com"><img src="../../images/bestfoodservicesweb_31.jpg" width="25" height="25"/></a></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

**YOU WILL NEED TO SCROLL DOWN TO SEE FOOTER IMAGES**

The demo shows how the my footer is suppose to look

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vd38Q/)
[Full Screen Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vd38Q/embedded/result/)

This is how it looks

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SUKkR/)
[Full Screen Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SUKkR/embedded/result/)

Comment: Your images aren't linked properly, please replace them with your domain included

Comment: @msbodetti What do you replace with your domain included? I used `img src=""` to find the file on my computer and that is what it gave me.

Comment: Have you uploaded it to a online server?

Comment: I have not uploaded it to an online server. I'm working out of Adobe Dreamweaver CC.

Comment: Well then we wont be able to see the images then on jsfiddle..

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the images that you cannot see. Those I didn't bother with. I did upload the pictures for you guys to see for the footer. If you scroll down, you can see the footer images and how one is centered and the other demo is left align

Comment: ahhh ok will check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe a tag wasn't closed. But this is what I added:

```
#footer{
   width: 860px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And it seems to be working. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/SUKkR/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: This worked, but all the images are lower than the main page footer. Is there a way to make it consistent so when clicking onto different pages the footer won't move?

Comment: Sure you can set the end_text div to relative position and bottom to 10px. Check out the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/SUKkR/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the `info_body` ul element in the second demo. Adding that should center the footer.

Also fix the img tag in Demo1, you missed out a `"` when defining the width.

Comment: The `info_body` isn't a part of the footer.